# Как отправить все выбранные чекбоксы

Tags: php, email, checkbox

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как выбрать все чекбоксы, которые отметили пользователи и отправить их на e-mail?

```
// Чекбоксы 
if (!empty($_POST['check'])) { 
  $check = $_POST['check']; 
  foreach($check as $index => $go) { 
    $index." - > ".$go."<br>"; 
  }; 
}; 

$message .= 'Базы данных 1С: ' . htmlspecialchars($go) . '<br />';

if(mail($emailAddress, $emailTheme, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers))) {
  $message .= '<br />Ваша заявка принята'; 
} else { 
  $message .= '<br />Ваша заявка не принята. Позвоните в IT отдел';
}

<h4>Выберите какие базы подключить</h4>
<div id="row_p1">
  <span class="radiobadge">
    <input type="checkbox" id="low" name="check[0]" value="База1">
    <label for="low">База1</label>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name" placeholder="Пример ФИО по кому выдать права" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput1">
  <span class="radiobadge">
    <input type="checkbox" id="med" name="check[1]" value="База2">
    <label for="med">База2</label>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="name2" id="name" placeholder="Пример ФИО по кому выдать права" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput1">
  <span class="radiobadge">
    <input type="checkbox" id="med" name="check[2]" value="База3">
    <label for="med">База3</label>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="name3" id="name" placeholder="Пример ФИО по кому выдать права" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput1">
  <span class="radiobadge">
    <input type="checkbox" id="high" name="check[3]" value="База4">
    <label for="high">База4</label>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="name4" id="name" placeholder="Пример ФИО по кому выдать права" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput1">
  <span class="radiobadge">
    <input type="checkbox" id="high" name="check[4]" value="БАРС(Подольск)">
    <label for="high">База5</label>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="name5" id="name" placeholder="Пример ФИО по кому выдать права" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   // Чекбоксы
             $check = isset($_POST['check']) ? $_POST['check'] : '';
             if (!empty($check))
{

    foreach ($check as $go)
    {
        $message .= 'Базы данных 1С: ' . htmlspecialchars($go) . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Вот так написал и все заработало.
Можно топик закрывать.